# How do i Extract integer value from a string in Unix

Tags: grep

when i type this command 
 /usr/local/afs7/bin/afs_paftools -a about.afs | grep TOTAL_DOCUMENTS

I get a result

TOTAL_DOCUMENTS = 74195

How i can extract the integer number(74195) after =
using grep command

Answer (score 2):

One way is to use grep:

```
$ echo "TOTAL_DOCUMENTS = 74195" | grep -o '[0-9]\+'
74195
```

or since you know, that it's the last field, use awk:

```
$ echo "TOTAL_DOCUMENTS = 74195" | awk '{print $NF}'
74195
```

or just use awk for the lot:

```
your-command -a about.afs | awk '/TOTAL_DOCUMENTS/{print $NF}'
```

Answer (score 0):

If there are no space:

```
TOTAL_DOCUMENTS=74195
```

Use this `awk`

```
echo "TOTAL_DOCUMENTS=74195" | awk -F= '{print $NF}'
74195
```